# Do power upgrade bonuses max out at 100%?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I am trying to upgrade EDI's "Unshackled AI" power to level 5, her power damage is currently at 80% and when I select "Tech Damage - Increase tech power damage by 30%" the power damage bar does not increase as I might have expected? Perhaps it "Tech Damage" doesn't mean what I think it does?

Do power upgrade bonuses max out or can they go beyond 100%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power Damage and Tech Damage are two different things.

Power Damage increases the damage of *all* powers, while Tech Damage only increases the damage of Tech powers (Incinerate, Cryo Blast, Overload, Sabotage). The problem here is that all of EDI's powers *are* tech powers, but because (for whatever reason) the last rank gives +tech power damage instead of +power damage, it doesn't show up on the bar (though it most certainly still applies).